# Reset all files affected by past commit to the state before that commit

Tags: git, git-reset

How do I reset all (and only) files affected by a given commit to the state before that commit?

I only need to reset the files in the commit, not the entire repository or single file/directory, and I don't want to have to type explicitly each file name.

There have been other commits after this one changing some of the files, so I can't just revert the commit due to conflicts with later commits.

**EDIT**
By "can't just revert" I meant that I tried it to see how far it takes me but failed at the very start.

Comment: What? A `revert` is _exactly_ what you need to do to avoid removing the changes from later commits. Sounds like you think that `git revert <some-commit>` works like `git restore --source <some-commit>~ -- some-files`... it does not.

Comment: Do you mean that, for the specified files, you want to revert the commit *and* any subsequent changes after that commit?

Comment: @David you could say so, yes. But not so for the specified files (explicit list of filenames) but for all files in that commit (so automatically detected).

Comment: @eftshift0 From where did you get that I "want to avoid removing  the changes from later commits"?  `$ git revert b94c781
Auto-merging html/de/login.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in html/de/login.html
`

Comment: `There have been other commits after this one changing some of the files, so I can't just revert the commit due to conflicts with later commits.`. Maybe I misread. Why are you worried about the conflict? The conflict means that _later_ commits changed the code that you were toucing in the commit you want to revert.... git can't just _guess_ how to deal with it when reverfting.... _and_ taking back the sections of code with conflicts specifically to what they were before the commit you want to revert is wrong because you would be skipping the later changes....

Comment: .... **if** in this specific case that is what you would like to do, then take the _other_ section of the conflict and live happily ever after. I guess you could even play with `--strategy` and `-X` to do this automagically.

Comment: Yes, it **does** sound like OP is unwittingly trying to reinvent the revert command.

Comment: Unless you want to rewrite your entire history (and even if you do), conflicts may be inevitable and you might just have to suck it up. Conflicts are not bad things; learn to handle them.

Comment: @eftshift0 Do you want to post an answer making use of --strategy or -X?

Comment: Not really.... if you used it and it worked, feel free to add an answer with the details for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout $that_commit^ -- $(git diff --name-only $that_commit^ $that_commit)
```

And now your current checkout will have the that commit's parent's versions of the files that differ in that commit from its parent, exactly as requested.  If you've got white space in your file names you'll want to shut off some of the shell's word splitting,

```
( IFS=$'\n'
  git checkout $that_commit^ -- $(git diff --name-only $that_commit^ $that_commit)
)
```

so it only takes newlines as separators in that command's expansions.

Comment: What are the dollar signs before `that-commit` for? Seems to me you're just confusing the OP; the commit has a name, no variable is involved.

Comment: Also, better to use `restore` than `checkout` perhaps.

Comment: Damn muscle memory :-) I, for one, can't cast stones at jthill for this.

Comment: I have gotten used to using `restore` with time. :-)

Comment: Also, perhaps `git diff --name-only` could be switched for `git show --pretty= --name-only $that_commit`.

Comment: Does the job. No spaces in my case. I do think though that there should be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Wondering if it would be the same as `git diff --name-only $that_commit^ $that_commit | xargs git checkout $that_commit^ --`

Comment: @matt well, using the shell variable means people can say for instance `that_commit=HEAD` or whatever name it's got and then just c&p the command. I like using tools to make life easier.

Comment: You and I know that, but the OP may not understand why the script as given doesn't work

Comment: @matt I'm going to keep writing for an audience that has or can pick up day-1 fundamentals like the `$` prefix meaning without any fuss. I think I'm pretty safe assuming anyone *completely* new to it is open to asking questions about their tools.